# GraphQL:ExecutionError: Deserialization can only be performed by Sitecore Administrators - Sitecore CLI error during Push operation

Tags: scs

**Background - Issue details:**

After successful setup of Sitecore CLI in higher environment (PreProd), we are able to do pull operation successfully. But while doing push operation, we are getting below error: We are using non-interactive login. However, both PULLL and PUSH is working fine in Dev instanc with the same same settings.

[image: Sitecore CLI Push error]

Below is our config in Identity server: -
`Sitecore.IdentityServer.DevEx.xml`

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <Settings>
>   <Sitecore>
>     <IdentityServer>
>       <Clients>
>         <!-- used to authenticate servers with client id and client secret -->
>         <CliServerClient>
>             <ClientId>SitecoreCLIServer</ClientId>
>             <ClientName>SitecoreCLIServer</ClientName>
>             <AccessTokenType>0</AccessTokenType>
>             <AccessTokenLifetimeInSeconds>3600</AccessTokenLifetimeInSeconds>
>             <IdentityTokenLifetimeInSeconds>3600</IdentityTokenLifetimeInSeconds>
>             <RequireClientSecret>true</RequireClientSecret>
>             <AllowOfflineAccess>false</AllowOfflineAccess>
>             <AllowedGrantTypes>                     
>                 <AllowedGrantType1>client_credentials</AllowedGrantType1>
>             </AllowedGrantTypes>
>             <ClientSecrets>
>                 <ClientSecret1>SuperSecret</ClientSecret1>>     
>             </ClientSecrets>
>             <AllowedScopes>
>                 <!-- this is required even if not a 'user' for Sitecore to like us -->
>                 <AllowedScope1>sitecore.profile.api</AllowedScope1>
>             </AllowedScopes>
>         </CliServerClient>
>       </Clients>
>     </IdentityServer>
>   </Sitecore>
> </Settings>
> ```

Below is CM  config - `Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.ClientCredentialsMapping.config`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:role="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/role/" xmlns:set="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/set/">
  <sitecore role:require="Standalone or ContentDelivery or ContentManagement">
    <federatedAuthentication>
      <identityProviders>
        <identityProvider id="SitecoreIdentityServer" type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.IdentityServer.IdentityServerProvider, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.IdentityServer" resolve="true">
          <transformations hint="list:AddTransformation">
            <transformation name="admin-ify client credentials users" type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Services.DefaultTransformation, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication">
              <sources hint="raw:AddSource">
                <claim name="client_id" value="SitecoreCLIServer" />
              </sources>
              <targets hint="raw:AddTarget">
                <claim name="name" value="sitecore\Admin" />
                <claim name="http://www.sitecore.net/identity/claims/isAdmin" value="true" />
              </targets>
              <keepSource>true</keepSource>
            </transformation>
          </transformations>          
        </identityProvider>
      </identityProviders>
    </federatedAuthentication>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

We set the below settings in `Sitecore.Services.GraphQL.Serialization.config` from one of the blog reference though its not recommended to fix this issue. But no luck.

```
<security type="Sitecore.Services.GraphQL.Hosting.Security.GraphQLSecurity, Sitecore.Services.GraphQL">
              <requireAuthentication>false</requireAuthentication>
              <requireApiKey>false</requireApiKey>
            </security>
```

Any help would be highly appreciated..Thanks